# Tango with Django -- Create 'Like' Button

Tags: python, django

I just wonder the reason why my 'like' button can not work.

Here's my like_category( ) function in views.py

```
@login_required
def like_category(request):

    cat_id = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cat_id = request.GET.get('category_id', '')

    likes = 0
    if cat_id:
        cat = Category.objects.get(id=int(cat_id))
        if cat:
            likes = cat.likes + 1
            cat.likes = likes 
            cat.save()

    return HttpResponse(likes)
```

And rango-ajax.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#likes').click(function(){
        var catid;
        catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
        $.get('/rango/like_category/', {category_id: catid}, function(data){
            $('#like_count').html(data);
            $('#likes').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

And here is category.html code:

```
<p>

<strong id="like_count">{{ category.likes }}</strong> people like this category

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <button id="likes" data-catid="{{ category.id }}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" action="/rango/like_category/">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
    Like
    </button>
{% endif %}

</p>
```

And here is part of the code in base.html:

```
{% load rango_extras %}

{% load staticfiles %}
<script src="{% static "js/jquery-1.11.1.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/rango-jquery.js" %}"></script>


<script src="{% static "js/jquery.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/rango-ajax.js" %}"></script>
```

And i find that my code is really the same exactly as the book, but why the 'like' button just couldn't work ?

Comment: Check that your js files are served correctly, try to open in your browser the js/rango-ajax.js file and ensure the contents are the same you show in your code, do the same with jquery.js dependencies...

Comment: yes, the rango-ajx.js code is the same as i show...

Comment: The other thing to check is accessing to the page: `/rango/like_category/?category_id=<cat_id>`. Replacing cat_id by a valid category id...let me know if it works.

Comment: try to print `cat_id` in your django view and post the result please

Comment: @avenet yes , it works. that's really strange.

Comment: The last part is to check if the js is executing just write console.log('hello') inside the functions, this way you can check that:

a) The click function executes
b) The results are retrieved from the server

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov i don't know where to print the result...

Comment: @avenet i just followed your advice and just write console.log('hello') inside the functions, but the terminal didn't print anything.

Comment: @avenet what should i do next ?

Comment: create a chat room and invite me and @avenet so that we could discuss things in detail

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov thank you so much. But i think i have figured out the reason that i failed.

Comment: Good. Answer your own question and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Because the code shown above is exactly the same as the book show, so maybe the problem is not happened there.

When i reviewed my code in base.html, i found that i have put `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
in the button, then i put this code above all the .js file and then everything goes well again.

So maybe the code order is very important and i have made the stupid mistake.

Anyway, thanks @avenet and @Jahongir Rahmonov